# Python regex search: repeated digit n times

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I don't understand why this won't return a match for the repeating digits:

```
import re
digits = '122223456789'
re.search(r'(\d)\4', digits)
```

Instead, I get "error: invalid group reference at position 4"

Comment: Did you mean `(\d)\1+`?

Comment: `re.search(r'((\d)\2+)', digits).group(1)` for an unknown number of repetitions. `r'\d{4}` if you are specifically looking for 4 repetitions.

Answer (score 11):

Because `\4` is a group reference in python-regex engine. If you want to specify a repetition you should use `{}`.

```
re.search(r'(\d){4}', digits)
```

Or if you want to match 4 repeated digit you need to reference it with `\1` since (\d) is the first captured-group.

```
re.search(r'(\d)\1{3}', digits)
```

Demo:

```
In [5]: re.search(r'(\d)\1{3}', digits).group(0)
Out[5]: '2222'
```

You can pass the group number to `group()` attribute of `search()` function in order to get the result of matched string by a specific group. Or just pass 0 to get the whole matched.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the `\number` in `(\d)\number` was a way to match the number of repeated patterns that was specific to the group. But it's like a perl variable number.